Can this be converted to run from a 12v power source?
I’d like to get this submersible UV bulb to run on 12v power by adding some type of voltage converter. Unfortunately neither the adaptor(?) which is on the power cord, nor bulb, has any information written on it. Can you help me determine how to do this?
The bulb is rated at 11W
Using a multimeter I get the following readings from the brown and blue wires on the output of the adaptor (bulb on)…

set at DC volts: 1.4v
set at AC volts: jumps around 60-80 mV
Set at amperage: steady 0.032 A





You could use a low-power automotive market inverter to produce mains voltage. Not the most efficient, but easy. Probably the kind that plug directly into the car outlet (what we used to call the cigarette lighter socket) would work at such low power.

Never, EVER, put an ammeter in parallel with a power source! You are basically shorting it out through the meter. Most likely you will damage the power source, the meter, or both! Always put ammeters in SERIES between a power source and load. In this case, the power source seems to be current limited so you got lucky.

Speff: Thanks, but I was hoping to determine if the bulb would run on dc power, be able to remove that 'adapter', and connect the blue and brown wires directly to 12v. Once going through the adapter, what type of current is being supplied to the bulb?

DoxyLover: Thanks for that advice, as I had no idea! Lesson learned. Any chance you can comment further on what that piece I'm probably wrongfully calling and adapter is doing?

I should add, the other little board closer to the wall plug is a timer
